# Promotion: writing articles about G&FH for gen. society newsletters

Tags: discussion, publicity

There have been questions on G&FH about the benefits of joining genealogical societies, but this article by [Terri O'Connell](http://www.findingourancestors.net/?p=2893) reminded me about the awesome opportunity members have to submit articles to their local society publications (#9 'Submit Your Writing').

There are two genealogy societies in my area that have excellent publications and they are always open to receiving articles about new technology and social media. I'm gonna write up a blurb about SE and submit it to the newsletter sometime this year. This is pretty doable :)

Anyone else want to commit to doing the same in their local area?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, every little bit helps.

But you should try to ensure that the effort is worth the trouble.

If you've got 50 people who read a publication, and 25 of them are computer saavy, and 10 of them actually go to check out G&FH and 4 of them sign up, and one of them becomes an active user ... well, then you've done something.

I thought it would be much easier than it has turned out to be, with regards to getting someone to visit the G&FH site and sign up and become an active participant, and then to do the all important thing and tell others.

Comment: True, so true! I guess we need to scatter seeds... some will fall on rocky soil, some will sprout but be choked out by the weeds, some will grow to flourish and eventually offer seeds of their own 20 or 30fold. Let's just hope that "1" turns out to be a [connector]:(http://www.escapefromcubiclenation.com/2010/08/23/connectors-mavens-and-salesmen-the-secret-to-your-success/) ;) Like I believe YOU are!

Comment: Damn, if you're finding it difficult, no wonder the rest of us are struggling.